# Using String Variable as Object in GWT

Tags: java, string, gwt, object, radio-button

I have 20 Radio Buttons which act as individual parking slots. I need to enable or disable based on the availability. Typically, I have declared them as

```
   final RadioButton oneA101 = new RadioButton("new name", "New radio button");
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
   String[] allSlotsToDisable={"oneA101","oneB101","oneA102","oneB102"};
    Object[] rb={};

    for(int i=0;i<allSlotsToDisable.length;i++){
        rb[i]=allSlotsToDisable[i];
        ((FocusWidget) rb[i]).setEnabled(false);
    }
```

DB returns a set of Radio Button that are meant to be disabled but they are returned as String. The returned string variable is name as the Object Name(oneA101 in this case). But, I can't use String variable to disable a Radio Button. How can I use the String variable to act on a Radio Button with the same Object Name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into a map, then you can access them by their names (or whatever other string you wan t to...)

```
private final Map<String,RadioButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<String,RadioButton>();
```

then later in the code, when creating the buttons:

```
final RadioButton oneA101 = new RadioButton("new name", "New radio button");
buttonMap.put("new name", oneA101);
```

then even later, when you need to address them:

```
RadioButton buttonToDoStuffWith = buttonMap.get("new name");
```

In your example

```
String[] allSlotsToDisable={"oneA101","oneB101","oneA102","oneB102"};

for(String toDisable:allSlotsToDisable){
    RadioButton button = buttonMap.get(toDisable);
    if(button!=null) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

(Of course beware of the life cycle of this hashmap, it ight cause problems if not used properly!)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ppeterka 66. That was a smashing success!!! Worked like magic. Thanks for supporting a new developer like me!!!